# Error when running code, backend:detachedConfiguration1 is both resolvable and consumable

Tags: java, gradle, angular-fullstack

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6824.png)
Does anyone know why this happens. This keeps going until reaching around 100+, and I do not know why.

I'm a bit new, so I have not tried to do much, but I did try adding the jcenter() input in this snippet.
`maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } jcenter()`
At one point, but that failed to work properly.